# Unlocking attributes

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to 'clean' this camera of mine, using a helper script but I keep getting this particular error:

```
RuntimeError: setAttr: The attribute 'camera.rotateOrder' is locked or connected and cannot be modified.
```

Likewise, in the Attribute Editor, under the Transform Attributes, as I try selecting all other options in the drop-down list of `Rotate Order`, it is fixed at the given value - `zxy`

Tried using python command - `cmds.setAttr( "camera" + ".rotateOrder" , 1 )`, gives me the same error as above. Likewise, I also did tried using `cmds.lockNode(l=False)`, it does not work out as well.

Also did try looking for this 'hidden' connection within the Node / Expression Editor as well as Hypergraph:Connections, all shown nothing.

As such, are there any ways in which I can unlock this particular attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
cmds.setAttr( camera + ".rotateOrder", lock = 0)
cmds.setAttr( camera + ".rotateOrder", desired_value_here)
```

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't working. Getting the same error. Think I will redo the camera, having to make sure there isn't any extra attributes etc. But thanks again for the help

Comment: Is this a referenced node?

Comment: You might be able to force unlock it with the Api. But if this is from a reference, you may not be able to keep it persistent.

Comment: After more checking, it does appears to be a referenced node. Thank you all